# AWS S3 not working but was working before without code change

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I had my project working yesterday pulling a profile image for each user from S3 yesterday but today when I went to load a page with the profile image it rendered the page without the image. I checked the logs and it looks like it is complaining about my AWS credentials not working. I tried making sure they were right, they were, I tried updating them to newly generated ones and that failed too.

Here is the code that interacts with AWS getting the profile image. When I start node it doesn't complain about the config file not loading. I tried outputting the values of the config file to the console (I used fake values for the secret and access key) and it worked so I know it is pulling the correct values.

**My code**

```
// Packages
var aws = require("aws-sdk");

var s3 = new aws.S3();

// Config
var config = require('../config/config');

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: config.aws_s3.secretAccessKey,
    accessKeyId: config.aws_s3.accessKeyId,
    region: config.aws_s3.region,
    sslEnabled: true
});

exports.profileImage = (req, res, next) => {
    var profileImageDB = req.user.avatar;
    var urlParams = {Bucket: config.aws_s3.logoBucket, Key: profileImageDB};
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, function(err, url){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.locals.url = url;
        next();
    });
};
```

**Error message**

```
{ CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sailhr/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Socket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:630:10)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:338:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  time: 2018-09-24T22:28:44.241Z,
  retryable: true,
  originalError: 
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     time: 2018-09-24T22:28:44.241Z,
     retryable: true,
     originalError: 
      { message: 'Connection timed out after 1000ms',
        code: 'TimeoutError',
        time: 2018-09-24T22:28:
```

I have even tried hard coding the values into the file with my function. That fails too. I can upload an image to S3 using the AWS credentials that I am using to download with so they keys are known to be working as of 5 minutes ago.

Anyone have any clue what might be happening? This seems like such a weird error to get when I haven't touched the code that uses it and the credentials have full access to S3 (for troubleshooting this only).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by moving my `var s3 = new aws.S3();` line below the `aws.config.update({` line. I am still not sure why it worked yesterday and not today though. That seems very odd to me. Still would be interested in why they might be. Maybe it has to do with if the values are the same something gets cached or the like

Comment: Were you running this code on the same machine yesterday (when it worked)? Did you make any recent changes to ~/.aws/credentials or to the AWS_ environment variables on that machine?

Comment: @jarmod I use AWS Cloud 9 for my IDE so same machine that never even rebooted. Server got stopped I think but that's it. I don't use the  ~/.aws/credentials but I plan to at some point.